# Evaluating a triple integral by converting using change of variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I have the double integral:

$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} e^{\frac {y}{(x+y)}} \;dy\; dx
$$

Ignore any difficulty this integral may have at the origin.

I was given a hint to simplify the exponent by taking it as a chunk. I thus set $v=\frac{y}{(x+y)}$, but am not sure what to do for you and go from there?

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: You say triple integral, but I only see two of them.

Comment: @mathworker21 sry the title should be a double integral. my apologies

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Put  $x+y=v$ and $y=u$ .Now using Jacobian $ dx dy=du dv$ .

And look the new region ...

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8cqzfvavn9

NOTE: take $u$-axis in place of $x$-axis .